# is it safe to completely format the HDD of a laptop that came pre installed with Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, sony-vaio

I have Sony Vaio svf15318snw pre installed with Windows 8. I have the recovery discs but they are useless due to the amount of scratches.

I want to completely wipe the HDD and install a new copy of Windows 8.

The problem is, the computer has a lot of OEM and reserved partitions. It also has a Assist button that starts BIOS, Recovery process and other things. Can i delete all the volumes, OEM partitions, reserved partitions and install a new copy of Windows 8?

I guess It'll mess up the Assist button but would I be able to open the BIOS settings without it (F2)? Would i be able to recover the factory state of the computer If i get another set of recovery discs later (after installing a new Windows)?

Comment: First make a disk image, so if there's a disaster, you can get back where you were.

Comment: I've already done it.

Comment: Then you're safe to try anything, knowing you can restore (usually, in less than an hour).

Comment: I still need an answer to the original question.

Comment: What do you mean by ***safe***? What constitutes *safe* and *unsafe*? What is the criteria?

Comment: Why don't you create a new set of recovery disks?

Comment: Not to be a Debbie Downer, but I would be a little careful. I had an OEM machine I wiped completely and reinstalled Windows 7 onto and it developed the idiosyncrasy that it required a "boot disc" (any copy of Windows 7) to be in the hard drive while booting. Not after booting. Just while booting. Otherwise, if the disc was missing, it wouldn't start. I believe this had something to do with the OEM bios. So beware - it may not break the PC (it didn't in my case) but it may not go flawlessly either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether it is safe or not, depends on what you are trying to do.

If you want to reinstall Windows 8 exactly as it was from the factory, **no**.

If you want to reinstall Windows 8 without any drivers and bloatware, **yes**.

The reserved partitions are there so that you can repair or reinstall Windows 8, without the discs.  These will also come with all of the drivers and software that originally came with the laptop.

If you format the partitions, and reinstall Windows 8 via a store bought disc, then you will have to find the drivers for the hardware in the laptop.  [Sony](http://www.sony.co.in/support/download/547903) appears to have the drivers for your laptop.

Comment: So as long as the drivers are available online, I can go ahead and wipe out the disk right? Also, I don't quite understand the concept of the Assist button which is a dedicated button next to the power button which gives access to BIOS menu and recovery options. Where does the computer store the functionality of that Assist button? is that included in the OEM or reserved partitions or is it built in on the motherboard? would it be affected by wiping out the disk?

Comment: As long as you have all the data on that drive saved (documents, videos, music, etc.), and you are comfortable reinstalling Windows and the drivers, then yes, you can format the drive.

Since the Assist Button allows access to BIOS, it would likely be stored in the computer's non-volatile RAM on the motherboard.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes F2 will still work.
2. Yes recovery disks will still work.